# Select a mailitem in ActiveExplorer

Tags: vba, outlook, mailitem

I have written a macro to open the path to a selected email in the results of the Outlook search.

The email is not automatically marked in the open folder so I search for the email in "ActiveExplorer". With .display, I can open the email, but I could not find a way to select the found email in "ActiveExplorer".

```vb
Public Sub MailOrdnerPfad()
  Dim obj As Object
  Dim Ordner As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim Betreff As String
  Dim Mail As MailItem

  Set obj = Application.ActiveWindow
  If TypeOf obj Is Outlook.Inspector Then
    Set obj = obj.CurrentItem
  Else
    Set obj = obj.Selection(1)
  End If
  Betreff = obj.ConversationTopic
  Set Ordner = obj.Parent
    Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = Ordner
    For Each Mail In Ordner.Items
        If Mail.ConversationTopic = Betreff Then
            Mail.Display
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Clear the original selection then add the found item.

```vb
Option Explicit


Public Sub MailOrdnerPfad()

    Dim obj As Object
    
    Dim Ordner As Folder
    Dim ordItem As Object
    
    Dim Betreff As String
    Dim myMail As MailItem

    Set obj = ActiveWindow
    If TypeOf obj Is Inspector Then
        Set obj = obj.CurrentItem
    Else
        Set obj = obj.Selection(1)
    End If
    
    If obj.Class = olMail Then
    
        Betreff = obj.ConversationTopic
        Debug.Print "Betreff: " & Betreff
    
        Set Ordner = obj.Parent
        Set ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = Ordner
        Debug.Print "Ordner.: " & Ordner
          
        For Each ordItem In Ordner.items
      
            If ordItem.Class = olMail Then
          
                Set myMail = ordItem
      
                Debug.Print "myMail.ConversationTopic: " & myMail.ConversationTopic
          
                If myMail.ConversationTopic = Betreff Then
                
                    ActiveExplorer.ClearSelection
                    ' myMail.Display
                    ActiveExplorer.AddToSelection myMail
              
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
      
    End If
    
End Sub
```