# How to select an e-mail using excel vba

Tags: vba, outlook

I've the code 'ListMailsInFolder' that works.
my issue is that I'd like to add a command to select an item from outlook. is there a command like olItem.select? what is the better alternative to solve it?

```
Sub ListMailsInFolder()
    Dim refCode As String ' define your reference
    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim thisMail As MailItem
    
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Colocar o foco na pasta Accounting Post Request
    Dim outFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set outFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Entrada")
    Set OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = outFolder
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem

    For Each olItem In outFolder.Items
        If InStr(olItem.Subject, 82848) > 0 Then
            
             'Here is the position that I need to add the code to select the email item
             'olItem.Select ???????
            Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error Resume Next
    Next olItem
    
    Stop
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [display email body of selected email in outlook as a message box in excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33261598/display-email-body-of-selected-email-in-outlook-as-a-message-box-in-excel)

Comment: Select a mailitem in ActiveExplorer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69379019/select-a-mailitem-in-activeexplorer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [Explorer.AddToSelection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.addtoselection) (where `Explorer` can be retrieved from Ap`plication.ActiveExplorer`). You might also need `Explorer`.[RemoveFromSelection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.removefromselection) / [IsItemSelectableInView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.isitemselectableinview)